# Pandas merge with MultiIndex for repeated columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, multi-index

I've got two DataFrames, containing the same information (length, width) about different aspects (left foot, right foot) of the same objects (people).

```
import pandas as pd

left_feet = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Length": [20, 30, 25],
        "Width": [8, 10, 9]},
    index=[0, 1, 2])

right_feet = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Length": [24, 30],
        "Width": [8, 10]},
    index=[2, 1])

print(left_feet)
   Length  Width
0      20      8
1      30     10
2      25      9

print(right_feet)
   Length  Width
2      24      8
1      30     10
```

I want to merge these into a single DataFrame, so I do this:

```
feet = pd.merge(left_feet, right_feet,
         left_index=True, right_index=True,
         suffixes=["_left", "_right"])

print(feet)
   Length_left  Width_left  Length_right  Width_right
1           30          10            30           10
2           25           9            24            8
```

Working with suffixes is cumbersome however. I would instead like the columns to be a MultiIndex, where the first level contains "left" and "right" and the second level contains "length" and "width".

What's the best way to do this?

Note: similar questions have been asked about concatenating aligned DataFrames, but this question is about a **join** (i.e. "merge") operation; the rows are not necessarily aligned and there may not always be corresponding rows.

Comment: I am referring to the concept of concatenation and merging/joining, not `pd.concat`. If the `concat` function can actually do joining (and not just concatenation) then that's a fine answer. Thanks for your answer, which is important if I need to use the `merge` function (perhaps for additional merging functionality).

Comment: No worries, it could have been clearer. I will edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `concat`, with `keys` parameter and `join='inner'`:

```
print(pd.concat([left_feet, right_feet], axis=1, keys=['Left','Right'], join='inner'))
    Left        Right      
  Length Width Length Width
1     30    10     30    10
2     25     9     24     8
```

Answer (score 4):

Because need `merge` or `join` first create `MultiIndex`es and then join:

```
left_feet.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['left'], left_feet.columns])
right_feet.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['right'], right_feet.columns])

feet = pd.merge(left_feet, right_feet,
         left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(feet)
    left        right      
  Length Width Length Width
1     30    10     30    10
2     25     9     24     8
```